# array_intersect with multidimensional array and non-multidimensional-array

Tags: php

I have following array with different font-styles:

```
Array
(
    [lightCuts] => Array (
            [0] => light
            [1] => light-italic
            [2] => light-condensed
            [3] => light-leftside
            [4] => light-extended
        )


    [regulaCuts] => Array (
            [0] => regular
            [1] => regular-italic
            [2] => regular-condensed
        )

    [mediumCuts] => Array (
            [0] => medium
            [1] => medium-italic
            [2] => medium-condensed
        )

    [boldCuts] => Array (
            [0] => bold
            [1] => bold-italic
            [2] => bold-condensed
        )

)
```

which should be used in a little shopping-cart. Each style costs 50$. If one buys two or more from the same weight (f.e 3 from lightCuts these 3 are cheeper).

Let´s say one chooses "light","light-italic","medium". How do I get as Output "light and light-italic cost 30$ and medium costs 50$". I think I need array_intersect and count() but can not figure out how.

```
$availableCuts = array(
"lightCuts" => array("light","light-italic","light-condensed","light-leftside","light-extended"),
"regulaCuts" => array("regular","regular-italic","regular-condensed"),
"mediumCuts" => array("medium","medium-italic","medium-condensed"),
"boldCuts" => array("bold","bold-italic","bold-condensed"),
);

$selectedCuts = array("light","light-italic","medium");
```

I do not stick on this array composition.

Comment: create array having numbers of set which font  corresponds, for example, with in_array. you will get [0,0,2] . then count the same values in the array and set the cost, if result >= 2

Comment: do you mean  in availableCuts each style has a unique id. selectedcuts has shares same id, then get all ids from availablecuts and check which ids are also in selectedcuts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php

$selectedArr = array();
foreach($availableCuts as $item) 
{
    if ($selected = array_intersect($item, $selectedCuts)) 
    {
        if (count($selected) == 1) $cost = 'cost 50$';
        elseif (count($selected) > 1) $cost = 'costs 30$';

        $selectedArr[] = implode(" and ", $selected) . " $cost";
    }
}

echo implode(" and ", $selectedArr);
// echoes "light and light-italic cost 30$ and medium costs 50$"
```